# Feature Selection Method for numerical X and categorical Y

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, feature-selection

What method we need to use to measure a corellation between numerical continuous X and categorical (binary) Y for feature selection?
The sources about this case are very confusing.

[This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/levels-of-measurement-statistics-and-python-implementations-8ff8e7867d0b) says, that we can use **Point-biserial correlation** for numerical X and categorical Y,
but in the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pointbiserialr.html) says:

> used to measure the relationship between a binary variable, x, and a
> continuous variable, y

and X must be array_like of bools, not Y.

Many articles prescribe the use of ANOVA, [example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-real-and-categorical-data/).
ANOVA in this case used like this:

```
fs = SelectKBest(score_func=f_regression, k=10)
```

so we send a bunch of features once, and there is no explanation of feature selection.
This is not appropriate, because I need to transparently get some values, on which a decision about corellation can be made, statistic/p-val or coefficient.

Some papers say, that we can use the distance covariance **dCov** for this task ([example pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.00081.pdf)),
and I found [this implementation](http://www.pymvpa.org/generated/mvpa2.misc.dcov.html) (possible)
but I'm not sure about it, because this approach is rarely mentioned.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What would you do in an easy setting with continuous features and a continuous outcome?

Comment: Note that we have existing threads on how to assess correlations between numerical & categorical variables, you might want to search the site & read them.  Also, be aware that typical uses of 'feature selection' are frowned upon. You might ask yourself why you need to do this & whether it will actually achieve what you want.  Then you might read some of our existing threads on the topic.